# facebook, post comment via php curl

Tags: facebook, curl

From one tutorials here:

[Post a reply on a comment in Facebook using cURL PHP / Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758501/post-a-reply-on-a-comment-in-facebook-using-curl-php-graph-api)

I tried to post comment to after one post, But return:

```
[type] => OAuthException [message] => (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

This is not my app acount wall's post id, I tried to my freinds wall, he have allowed my app, I can post a post to his wall, but failed in a comment, I got the post id via
`https://graph.facebook.com/<his fid>/feed?access_token=140XXXXXXXXXXX`, so the post id has no problem.

What steps have I missed?

```
$fbId = '100001102789652_233997699980321';
$accessToken = '140XXXXXXXXXXXX';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fbId}/comments";

$attachment =  array(
        'access_token'  => $accessToken,
        'message'       => "Hi comment",
);

// set the target url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$comment = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$comment = json_decode($comment, TRUE);
print_r($comment);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($attachment));
```

as you can't post an array

Comment: you are right, should put a full longer access_token. I am puzzled, when i post a post to friends's wall, only require short access_token, but a comment needs a longer access_token.